# How to make my Bottom Bar fixed in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

**Hey**

I have my bottom bar out the Scroll View component,But it still scroll with the other components.
How can i make it fixed ?

"

```
<SafeAreaView styles={SafeViewAndroid.AndroidSafeArea}>
<View style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff", padding: 15 }}>
<HeaderTabs activeTab={activeTab} setActiveTab={setActiveTab} />
<SearchBar cityHandler={setCity} />
</View>
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
<Categories />
<RestaurantItems restaurantData={restaurantData} />
</ScrollView>
<Divider width={1} />
<BottomTabs />
</SafeAreaView>
```

"

[Entire Code Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzTea.png)

Comment: Nothing outside the scroll view will scroll

Comment: I'm viewing it in the Web not on an emulator could it be the issue ?

Comment: On the web you can try position attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex proportions to separate the  and  components, as below

```
<SafeAreaView styles={SafeViewAndroid.AndroidSafeArea}>
   <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff", padding: 15, flex : 1 }}>
     <HeaderTabs activeTab={activeTab} setActiveTab={setActiveTab} />
     <SearchBar cityHandler={setCity} />
  </View>
  <View style= {{flex : 3 }}>
    <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      <Categories />
      <RestaurantItems restaurantData={restaurantData} />
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
  <View style= {{flex : 1 }}>
    <Divider width={1} />
    <BottomTabs />
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by styling your button component as -

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={{
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 50,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }}
    onPress={() => {
        console.log('Button Pressed')
    }}
>
    <Text>Hello Bottom Button</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```